# Проблемы с главным потоком в WPF .Net 8

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-8

Ломаю голову над проблемой часов 6, надеюсь тут помогут. Имеется WPF приложение на .Net 8. В главном окне есть обычно текстовое поле с биндингом на нужно свойство в `DataContext`:

```
 <Grid>
    <TextBlock FontSize="22" Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="50" Width="100"/>
</Grid>
```

Сам дата контекст окна задается в code-behind:

```
using CryptoAnalys.ViewModels;
using Infrastructure;
using Infrastructure.Abstractions;
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Windows;
using UseCases;

namespace CryptoAnalys
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var config = new MediatRServiceConfiguration()
        {
            AutoRegisterRequestProcessors = true,
        };

        config.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(typeof(GetIsApiExistsQuery).Assembly);

        var services = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton<IGrpcApiService, GrpcApiService>()
            .AddMediatR(config)
            .RegisterGrpc()
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        var sender = services.GetRequiredService<IMediator>();

        DataContext = new MainViewModel(sender);
    }
  }
}
```

И, собственно, сам `ViewModel`:

```
namespace CryptoAnalys.ViewModels
{
 public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
 {
    string _text;

    public MainViewModel(IMediator sender) : base(sender)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(10);

            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
               Text = "123";
            });
        });
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get => _text;
        set
        {
            if (_text == value)
                return;

            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    } 
  }
}
```

В общем, всё по классике, но тут начинается сама настоящая магия. По абсолютно непонятной причине `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke` не выводит на экран текст `'123'`. Притом если поменять код:

```
  Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(10);

            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
               Text = "123";
            });
        });
```

на

```
Task.Run(async () =>
     {
         Text = "123";
     });
```

Всё будет работать корректно. Если убрать

```
Task.Run(async () => ...
```

И оставить только конструктор с инициализацией:

```
public MainViewModel(IMediator sender) : base(sender)
{
    Text = "123";
}
```

Всё также будет работать как следует. Самое интересное: если поместить код в диспетчер, но уже без таска, `'123'` снова не показывается:

```
public MainViewModel(IMediator sender) : base(sender)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
       Text = "123";
    });
}
```

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Upd 1:
Код ViewModelBase:

```
using MediatR;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace CryptoAnalys.ViewModels
{
  public class ViewModelBase
  {
    public ViewModelBase(ISender sender)
    {
        Sender = sender;
    }

    public ViewModelBase()
    {
        
    }

    public ISender Sender { get; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }
}
```

Что примечательно, создал на форме кнопку с командой в том же ViewModel:

```
<Grid>
  <Button Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}" Height="50" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Button>
  <TextBlock FontSize="22" Text="{Binding Text}" Height="50" Width="100"/>
</Grid>
```

Код Vm поменялся на следующий:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  string _text;

  public MainViewModel() : base()
  {
    LoadedCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(Loaded);           
  }

  public RelayCommand<object> LoadedCommand { get; }

  public string Text
  {
    get => _text;
    set
    {
        if (_text == value)
            return;

        _text = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private void Loaded(object obj)
  {
    Text = "123";
  }
}
```

Loaded выполняется всё синхронно и даже в таком случае изменение текста не происходит(
На всякий случай класс команды:

```
public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
  private readonly Predicate<T> _canExecute;
  private readonly Action<T> _execute;

  public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute)
   : this(execute, null)
  {
    _execute = execute;
  }

  public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute)
  {
    if (execute == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
    }
    _execute = execute;
    _canExecute = canExecute;
  }

  public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
  {
    return _canExecute == null || _canExecute((T)parameter);
  }

  public void Execute(object parameter)
  {
    _execute((T)parameter);
  }

  public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
  {
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема найдена: Базовый класс ViewModelBase не реализует интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: ```Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke``` вам и не нужен для отображения данных во view так как вы работаете с vm. 
То есть вы не взаимодействуете с ui и выходить из потока в главный вам не зачем. Удалите эту чать кода, она вам не нужна.